# Get the Date since active status for record in sql in different services

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find out date from which that particular client is active regardless of different service provided by that client. I am able to get the latest state but that doesn't help me with what I am looking for!!

Can you guys please share your thought or give guidance on on how to do this?

Here is my table.[image]

I am expecting following result

[image]

Here is what I am getting with following query

[image]

here is the query, it's not meant for above tables but idea is the same to get the last row of each name for each different services. Here is the query.

```
select FIRST,LAST,GENDER
from    Employees e
join    (
        select  row_number() over (
                    partition by emp_id
                    order by startdate desc) as rn
        ,       EMP_ID
        ,       STATUS
        from    EMPSTATES
        where   STARTDATE <= '2016-08-19'
        ) h
on      e.EMP_ID = h.EMP_ID
        and h.rn = 1 -- Only last row
where   h.STATUS = 'A'
order by FIRST,LAST
```

Comment: Check if this works - `SELECT Name, MAX(Status) AS STATUS, MAX(STARTDATE) AS SINCE FROM YourTable GROUP BY Name, Status`

Comment: Wonderfully asked question, you're communicating very well everything we need to answer you.   You are getting more complicated than what you require here...no need for row_numbering here.  Use aggregates (max) as suggested by techspider above

Comment: forgot to add `WHERE Status = 'Active'`; but you should be able to figure out in these lines without complicating your code

Comment: Thank you guys for your valuable suggestions...working on these suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ROW_NUMBER()` function in `CTE`, you can achieve it

```
;WITH cteEmployeeStatus
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY EmpName
                ORDER BY startdate) as rn
        ,EMP_ID
        ,StartDate
        ,EmpName
        ,STATUS
        FROM 
            EMPSTATES
        WHERE  
            STARTDATE <= '2016-08-19'
            AND  Status = 'Active'
)
SELECT EMP_ID, EmpName, StartDate AS Since FROM cteEmployeeStatus
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks..Krishraj..Working on this.

Comment: Sorry Friends, Just did not had chance to work on this. I kind of explained wrong here in my issue. There are two tables, 1) Employees 2) EMPSTATS. They both are connected via EMP_ID.  We can get Employee Name only from Employees and not from the EMPSTATS, so I can not do partition by EMPNAME, We can get EMP_ID, StartDate, Department_ID, Status from EMPSTATS and Employee name from employees any idea how to get this done now, since I am confuse more. THANKS in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() and CTE:

```
;with cte as(
    SELECT Name, [status], [since], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY [since] asc) as rn
    FROM Employees
    WHERE --add your where statement here
)

Select Name, [status], [since]
From cte
Where Rn = 1
```

Edit, based on comments:

```
with cte as( 
SELECT e.FIRSTNAME, 
       e.LASTNAME, 
       s.[STATUS], 
       s.STARTDATE, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.emp_ID ORDER BY s.startdate asc) as rn
FROM Employees e 
join EMPSTATES s 
on e.EMP_ID=s.EMP_ID 
WHERE s.STARTDATE <= '2016-09-06' 
AND [Status] ='A'
 ) 

Select FIRSTNAME, 
       LASTNAME, 
       [STATUS], 
       STARTDATE
From cte 
Where Rn = 1
```

Or with top 1 with ties:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES 
       e.FIRSTNAME, 
       e.LASTNAME, 
       s.[STATUS], 
       s.STARTDATE
FROM Employees e 
join EMPSTATES s 
on e.EMP_ID=s.EMP_ID 
WHERE s.STARTDATE <= '2016-09-06' 
AND [Status] ='A'
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.emp_ID ORDER BY s.startdate asc)
```

Comment: Thanks @gofr1 ....working on this...looks like all of your solutions/sugestion gonna work...thanks again all of you.

Comment: My pleasure! If any of the answers helps, feel free to upvote/accept them! :)

Comment: Sorry Friends, Just did not had chance to work on this. I kind of explained wrong here in my issue. There are two tables, 1) Employees 2) EMPSTATS. They both are connected via EMP_ID.  We can get Employee Name only from Employees and not from the EMPSTATS, so I can not do partition by EMPNAME, We can get EMP_ID, StartDate, Department_ID, Status from EMPSTATS and Employee name from employees any idea how to get this done now, since I am confuse more. THANKS in advance

Comment: So? Put all your need in cte, then use this  cte in another with row_number, than select from last cte, where rn=1

Comment: Thanks @gofr1 for quick reply. I think I am still not getting the right result, since I am doing something wrong at the first place.

Comment: If you are not getting the right results in the first place, why you not asked question about it? :)

Comment: My issue is, I would like to get EMPLOYEE basic infomation like, firstname, lastname, address, DOB which I can get from EMPLOYEES table and I am also looking for status which I can get only from EMPSTAT table. The link between EMPLOYEES and EMPSTAT is EMP_ID. I just looked at EMPSTATS , I found employees active in both department in HEATING AND COOLING like PETER in my picture above. I just need to get all his basic info one time only. So i have to pick PETER in such a way that if he is active in 2 department then just pick one which is oldest.

Comment: If you put all data from joining this tables in CTE1, then select all from first cte in CTE2 with row_number over partition by empname order by date asc, then select from CTE2 where rn = 1 should do trick

Comment: Or even better, make CTE with results of joining table, then you select top 1 with ties fron this CTE order by row_number partition by empname order by somedate asc

Comment: with cte as(
    SELECT e.FIRSTNAME, e.LASTNAME, s.[STATUS], s.STARTDATE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.emp_ID ORDER BY s.startdate asc) as rn
    FROM Employees e
    join
    EMPSTATES s
    on
    e.EMP_ID=s.EMP_ID
    WHERE 
             s.STARTDATE <= '2016-09-06'
            AND  Status = 'A'--add your where statement here
)

Select FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, [STATUS], STARTDATE,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY firstname ORDER BY startdate asc) as rn
From cte
Where Rn = 1

Comment: Did you mean this way. I am sorry but I always have difficulties in some sort of understanding of row_number over partition.PLEASE help.

Comment: Just make a query that gets data you need (name, status, date). Put inside cte. Than you can add row_number with partition by name, and order on date. You need partition so for each name there will be new list of numbers from 1 to n where n is how many rows with that name was

Comment: Put this row_number in order by part and add top 1 with ties to your select. But at first be sure that for any name the 1 row_number is for oldest date

Comment: OK got it, thanks for explaining the function. Working on it.

Comment: I don't remember if you can use row_number when partition by column is from one table and order by is from another... Should work well, though. If so you can even use one query.

Comment: Add some query's to my answer, based on our conversation. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below query..

```
        SELECT  e.FIRSTNAME, 
                        e.LASTNAME, 
                        s.[STATUS], 
                        MIN(s.STARTDATE) Since
        FROM Employees e 
            JOIN EMPSTATS s 
                on e.EMP_ID=s.EMP_ID 
        WHERE s.STARTDATE <= '2016-09-06' 
                       AND [Status] ='A'
        GROUP BY e.FIRSTNAME, 
                            e.LASTNAME, 
                            s.[STATUS]
```

Comment: Sorry Friends, Just did not had chance to work on this. I kind of explained wrong here in my issue. There are two tables, 1) Employees 2) EMPSTATS. They both are connected via EMP_ID.  We can get Employee Name only from Employees and not from the EMPSTATS, so I can not do partition by EMPNAME, We can get EMP_ID, StartDate, Department_ID, Status from EMPSTATS and Employee name from employees any idea how to get this done now, since I am confuse more. THANKS in advance